# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6

Вот полный текст ошибки (при компиляции ошибки нету. Я не могу попасть на эту страницу ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет. У меня тут возникла проблема с корзиной. Я не могу понять как ее решить.
Прошу помочь.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1;
using WebApplication1.Interface;
using WebApplication1.mocks;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.Repository;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("dbsettings.json").Build();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDBContent>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAllTicket, TicketRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITicketCategory, CategoryRepository>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => ShopCart.GetCart(sp));


builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();

}



app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSession();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    AppDBContent content = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDBContent>();
    DBObject.Initial(content);
}


app.Run();
```

Код из самого контроллера

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.Repository;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ShopCartController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TicketRepository _gameRep;
        private readonly ShopCart _shopCart;
        public ShopCartController(TicketRepository gameRep, ShopCart gameCart)
        {
            _gameRep = gameRep;
            _shopCart = gameCart;
        }
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var items = _shopCart.getShopItems();
            _shopCart.listShopItems = items;
            var obj = new ShopCartViewModel
            {
                shopCart = _shopCart
            };
            return View(obj);
        }
        public RedirectToActionResult addtoCart(int id)
        {
            var item = _gameRep.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
            if(item != null)
            {
                _shopCart.AddtoCart(item);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Код из Модели

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ShopCart
    {
        private readonly AppDBContent appDBContent;
        public ShopCart(AppDBContent appDBContent)
        {
            this.appDBContent = appDBContent;
        }
        public string ShopCartId { get; set; }
        public List<ShopCartItem> listShopItems { get; set; }
        public static ShopCart GetCart(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            ISession session = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;
            var context = services.GetService<AppDBContent>();
            string shopCartid = session.GetString("Cartid") ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            session.SetString("Cartid", shopCartid);
            return new ShopCart(context) { ShopCartId = shopCartid };
        }

            public void AddtoCart(Ticket ticket)
            {
                appDBContent.ShopCartItem.Add(new ShopCartItem
                {
                    ShopCartId = ShopCartId,
                    ticket = ticket,
                    price = ticket.Price,


                });
                appDBContent.SaveChanges();
            }
        public List<ShopCartItem> getShopItems()
        {
            return appDBContent.ShopCartItem.Where(c => c.ShopCartId == ShopCartId).Include(s => s.ticket).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приводите полностью текст ошибки (это комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений").

Comment: Дело в том, что при компиляции ошибки нету. Я не могу попасть на эту страницу

Comment: внес комментарий в текст

Comment: `ShopCartController` в конструкторе принимает параметр `TicketRepository`, а в DI-контейнере задан только `IAllTicket`. Так что либо в конструкторе поменяйте тип параметра, либо в DI-контейнере.

Comment: Примечание: `ShopCart` гвоздями приколочен к `IServiceProvider`. Фактически тут вместо паттерна Dependency Injection используется анти-паттерн Service Locator. | Основная идея DI - освободиться от внешних зависимостей. А тут прямая зависимость от конкретного DI-контейнера. Попробуйте заменить его на любой другой...

Comment: как можно сделать. я пока не очень в asp

Comment: это еще net 6  //

Comment: ASP - это технология времен Билла Гейтса, не имеющая отношения к .NET, а код писался на VBScript. Так, на будущее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShopCartController` в конструкторе принимает параметр `TicketRepository`:

```
public ShopCartController(TicketRepository gameRep, ShopCart gameCart)
```

А в DI-контейнере задан только `IAllTicket`:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAllTicket, TicketRepository>();
```

Так что либо в конструкторе поменяйте тип параметра, либо в DI-контейнере.

```
// Или так
public ShopCartController(IAllTicket gameRep, ShopCart gameCart)

// Или так
builder.Services.AddTransient<TicketRepository>();
```

---

---

Примечание: `ShopCart` гвоздями приколочен к `IServiceProvider`. Фактически тут вместо паттерна Dependency Injection используется анти-паттерн Service Locator.

Основная идея DI - освободиться от внешних зависимостей. А тут прямая зависимость от конкретного DI-контейнера.

Попробуйте заменить его на любой другой - при правильной реализации DI для этого достаточно заменить лишь код Composition Root - место, где задаются зависимости: все эти `AddSingleton`, `AddTransient`, `AddScoped`.

А вам также придётся переписывать код `ShopCart`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Просто делал тз и не знал как сделать, а нужно было закончить еще в воскресенье. В одном из вопрос здесь нашел решение, но не знал правильно ли менять репозиторий на iallticket, а в том видео с уроком у него был репозиторий, а не iallticket и все работало, хотя он писал на .net 5, а я на 6. Я поставлю галочку. Еще раз спасибо.